# How do I make a file dialog for a custom forms that does the same thing as the autogenerated URL selector?

Tags: qgis, qt-designer

I used QT Designer to build a custom form for attribute entry. One of the attributes is for storing a file path of a permit document as a string. With the auto-generated forms, there was a URL selector which worked fine. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do the same thing with my custom form UI that I made in QT designer. As it stands right now, users will have to manually enter the file path by copy and pasting but ideally I would like to give them the same functionality as the dialog box that appears when you use the url selector.

I looked around at QFileDialog but most of what I get is form coding in applications and I'm not sure how to finesse it into working with a layer form UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this code to accept a QLineEdit object so that I could connect this same function to multiple buttons and pass in the appropriate field that I wanted to have filled out.

I connected it with: `someButton.clicked.connect(selectFile(someQLineEditObject))`

When you click the button, a dialog box opens and fills the QLineEdit with the path to the selected file.

```
#opens a file selection dialog when browse is clicked
def selectFile(item):
    #create an instance of QFileDialog
    fileDlg = QFileDialog()
    #Sets the field text as the selected file path
    item.setText(fileDlg.getOpenFileName())
```